# MediaPlayer постепенное повышение громкости

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Как сделать постепенное повышение громкости трека, и постепенное понижение громкости трека. Треков в приложении 2, и проигрываются они с кроссфейдом. То есть в начале трек должен постепенно в громкости возрасти, а в конце постепенно в громкости убавить.... Я сделал с помощью countDownTimer, но это не очень правильно. Может что посоветуете? Треки проигрываю с помощью MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  //Увеличение громкости  
  audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,                 
  AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
  //Уменьшение громкости
  audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Просто добавьте таймер и выполняйте этот код по таймеру

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если несколько объектов MediaPlayer, то как привязать определенный AudioManager к определенному MediaPlayer.

Comment: Хм честно говоря не работал с этим :) Можете глянуть Sound Pool - с его помощью тоже можно воспроизводить медиа файлы и даже накладывать их друг на друга.